# The equivalent of nested functions in php

Tags: php

I need to refactor some of the legacy code we're using on a wordpress project to object oriented. One area where there's a lot of duplication of code is when setting the title of the page, as you can see below, within the setTitle function.

Nested functions don't seem to work in PHP. However, assuming it would work, the below code, should accomplish what I am trying to do.

In the setTitle function, all I am trying to do is take in a string and execute the code within somehow and have it successfully call `add_filter` with the string that was passed in, which will successfully set the title. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

MyControllerClass.php

```
public function setTitle($title) {
   function t($t) {
     $t['title'] = $title; return $t;
   }
   add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 't' );
   return $this;
}
```

Then, later in a different class..

`$controller->setTitle('My Homepage')->renderHomePage();`

Comment: There is no such thing as a nested function in PHP.... what you have is simply a function t() that will only be defined if setTitle() is called, but otherwise it shares absolutely nothing with setTitle(), no variable scope, nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an anonymous function with the `use` statement. 
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#functions.anonymous

Try this.

```
public function setTitle($title) { 
   add_filter( 'document_title_parts', function ($t) use ($title) {
     $t['title'] = $title; return $t;
   });
   return $this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that already, $title is undefined.

Comment: Well, you guys are missing `use($title)` so yea, of course it's undefined. No clue why the downvote tho.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend like they said I forgot the use. Try it now

Comment: Thanks for the help @bassxzero, its working after adding the `use()`.